# Incorrect placement of let

Tags: rust

I'm making a file to hold a bunch of things I learn about Rust but I'm getting compile errors regarding my `let` statements:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]

fn main() {}

let a = (1, "hello");
let b: (i32, &str) = (1, "hello");

enum Character {
    Digit(i32),
    Other,
}

let ten = Character::Digit(10);
let four = Character::Digit(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `let` in functions. Global variables can be defined with `static` keyword, and they have a lot of limitations compared to the local variables.

Please read [the official book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-beta/book/), it covers questions like this.

Comment: Yes, it's just `const` defines not a variable but an inlineable constant.